# updating the second occurance of value in a column Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataset in which I want to pivot column 2 and column 3.
Column 3 is the column name and column 2 is its value.
But for each id, there could be a duplicate value in col3.

| id | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | foo |
| 1 | e | foo |

to

| id | foo | foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | e |

Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1'],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
                   'col3': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'baz']})
```

As we cannot have 2 columns with the same name in a dataframe I tried to group them by id and find the second occurrence then update it by adding '2' at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1', '1'],
                   'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
                   'col3': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'biz', 'baz']})

# Find rows with duplicate values in col3 for the same id
duplicated_rows = df[df.duplicated(subset=['id', 'col3'], keep=False)]

# Iterate over each group of duplicated rows and update the second occurrence
for id, group in duplicated_rows.groupby('id'):
    mask = (group.index != group.index[0])  # Select the second occurrence
    df.loc[mask, 'col3'] = df.loc[mask, 'col3'] + '2'  # Update the value by adding '2'

print(df)
```

But I get this error:
*IndexError: Boolean index has wrong length: 4 instead of 7*

How can we update the second occurrence?
Any other solution is also appreciated.

Comment: From the accepted answer in the suggested duplicate, change `variable` to `col3`, and `value` to `col2`, and that should basically do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) :

```
out = (
        df.assign(col3=df.groupby(["id", "col3"])
                          .cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
                          .radd("_").radd(df["col3"]))
        .pivot(index="id", columns="col3", values="col2")
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()
      )
```

​
Output :

```
print(out)
​
  id bar_1 baz_1 baz_2 biz_1 foo_1 foo_2
0  1     b     c     g     f     a     d
1  2     e   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```